# What does the TotalStorageWaitTime parameter mean in profile of impala?

Tags: impala

The same query statement, performance is unstable in impala. Sometimes it takes about 2 seconds to query, and sometimes it takes about 10 seconds. When the execution is slow, the TotalStorageWaitTime and scannerThreadsTotalWallClockTime parameters are relatively large. What is the relationship between these two parameters, and where is the bottleneck of slow query?

[part of profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RZhy.png)